# How does email translation work with django allauth?

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-i18n

I'm using the most excellent django-allauth to handle authentication.  All is well, but I have an issue with the email translations.

First, allauth is definitely using my template.

- I ran: django-admin.py makemessages -l ir -i settings.py
- This created: my_app/locale/ir/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
- In django.po, I make this change:

  templates/account/email/email_confirmation_subject.txt:3
   msgid "Confirm E-mail Address"
   msgstr "FARSI Confirm E-mail Address"
- Then to test, a user signs up on a page where the language is set (), but the email sent is not using what I put in the msgstr above.

I'd like to know have I misunderstood something, is this even how it's supposed to work?

Comment: If the language is not set explicitly, it will use the default language of the system (in your case, its English). Make sure you read through [this section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) which explains how django knows which language to use. You are missing this part.

Comment: Yep, this is nothing to do with allauth, I just needed to read how django determines language.  Thanks,