# How to setup email translation with Django Allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-i18n

I am trying to setup translations for emails with django-allauth.
I have rewritten my templates, translated my .po files and complied them.

The html translations work fine but for some reason **just the emails** don't get translated.

I have properly configured translations following the django tutorial
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

The related question doesn't help:
[How does email translation work with django allauth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067488/how-does-email-translation-work-with-django-allauth)

Package versions:
Django==1.10
django-allauth==0.27.0

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with `django-allauth==0.32.0` and `Django==1.11.1`. Translations that are shipped with `allauth` are simply outdated or incomplete. In my project, for example, an email with a link to reset the password was always in English (in default language `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'`) although the user set the language to Czech.

In `.po` file for Czech translations: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/django.po#L408 is this e-mail translation marked as `fuzzy` – so translations are not used. The same applies to other languages I've checked (`de`, `es`...).

The reason is explained in this comment from the author of `allauth`:

> The allauth templates are merely meant as a starting point, something
>   to get you going quickly. Hence, I do not treat issues in the
>   translations as blocking for release, which can result in translations
>   getting left behind. Feel free to submit pull requests to fill in the
>   gaps.

*Source:* https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1113#issuecomment-141189606

I think there are two ways to solve this issue:

1. Fix/update translations on https://www.transifex.com/django-allauth/django-allauth/, submit pull request on Github and wait for a new release.
2. **My recommendation:** copy all templates from `allauth` to your project,  make your own `*.po` files and ignore all default translations/templates. Do not forget that e-mail templates are in `*.txt` so you must call `makemessages` this way: `python manage.py makemessages ... --extension html,txt,py`.

Comment: Nice answer, just to illustrate it, I post a related link [Django translations of third party apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52004442/842935)